# For $Y \sim N_n(X\theta,\sigma^2I_n)$ show that an unbiased linear estimator, $b'Y$, of $c'\theta$ is independent of $Y'(I-P_x)Y$

Tags: self-study, distributions, independence, unbiased-estimator, multivariate-normal-distribution

For $Y \sim N_n(X\theta,\sigma^2I_n)$ show that an unbiased linear estimator, $b'Y$, of $c'\theta$ is independent of $Y'(I-P_x)Y$

Ok...first some notation: $'$ means transpose and $P_x$ is the projection matrix $X(X'X)^-X'$

**Given**: the distribution of $Y$, $X$ is an $n$ by $m$ matrix of rank $r \leq m < n$, $\sigma^2$ is unknown, and $c'\theta$ is estimable (by $b'Y$ which need not be the BLUE). I have to find the denominator $D$ such that $\frac{b'Y-c'\theta}{D}$ follows a t distribution.

I've actually pieced this together for the most part. We known that if $U \sim N(0,1)$ and $V \sim \chi^2(r)$ are independent, $\frac{U}{\sqrt{V/r}}$ follows a t distribution.

Well, $b'Y-c'\theta \sim N(0, \sigma^2b'b)$ so $\frac{b'Y-c'\theta}{\sqrt{\sigma^2b'b}} \sim N(0, 1)$

I also know that $(1/\sigma^2)Y'(I-P_x)Y \sim \chi^2(n-r)$. I now have a $U$, $V$, and $r$ that cancel out the unknown $\sigma^2$, but I still have to show that $U$ and $V$ are independent...

This is easy if $b'Y$ is the BLUE because then $b'Y = c'\hat{\theta} =c'P_xY$. All that's required is to show $Cov(P_xY,(I-P_x)Y)=P_xCov(Y,Y)(I-P_x)'=\sigma^2P_x(I-P_x)=0$ due to the idempotence of $P_x$, and that suffices to show independence.

However, in this problem, I need to show that this holds for any $b'Y$ regardless of if it's the BLUE or not...that's where I'm stumped. I can't just show independence with $Cov(b'Y,(I-P_x)Y)$ anymore, and I haven't found any other way to do so...

I know this is a long winded one, but if anyone can give me any insight as to how to finish this that'd be amazing!

**UPDATE**

I may have figured it out, but I'm not sure if all of my assumptions are correct.

I think I successfully proved that $c'\theta$ is estimable if and only if $c$ is contained in the column space of $X'X$. Thus, we can write $c = X'Xv$ for some vector $v$.

Since $c=X'b$ that means $X'Xv = X'b$ so $b = Xv$.

Now, $Cov(b'Y,(I-P_x)Y) = \sigma^2(b'(I-P_x)') = \sigma^2(v'X'(I-P_X)) = \sigma^2(v'X'-v'X'P_x)$ and since $P_xX=X$ doesn't $X'P_x = X'$?

Comment: This sound like homework?  Perhaps teh self-study tag is in order?

Comment: Please add the self-study tag indeed.

Comment: My bad... I'm kinda new to this place.

Comment: Are you sure that your projection matrix is defined correctly. Did you mean $P_{x} = X(X'X)^{-1}X' $ or $P_{x} = (X'X)^{-1}X'$?

Comment: While I haven't worked this out, my suggestion would be to would be to play with $Cov[b'Y,(I-P_{x})Y]= E[(b'Y)((I-P_{x})Y)] - E[b'Y] E[(I-P_{x})Y]$ a little, keeping in mind that $b'Y$ in an unbiased estimator of $c'\theta$. See where that takes you.

Comment: I think my projection matrix is defined correctly. I'm given that $X$ is of rank $r \leq m < n$ so no guarantee of full rank there...

Comment: coolBeanz If that is the case then should it be $X(X'X)^{-}X'$ as @MattBrems suggested?

Comment: Oh shoot! You're right. I hadn't even noticed that. Typo on my part. Just edited to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in that you don't know that $b'Y$ is the BLUE, but you *do* know that it is a linear unbiased estimator.  Do the properties of covariance you wish to use for $b'Y$ rely on being the *best* linear unbiased estimator, or simply the linear and unbiased properties of the estimator?

You are, however, incorrect in your specification of your projection matrix.  The projection matrix $P$ is generally $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$, unless your $X$ is not full rank, in which case it should be $X(X'X)^-X'$, where $(X'X)^-$ indicates the generalized inverse of $X'X$.  Per the problem, since $X$ is $m\times n$ where $m<n$, $X$ cannot be invertible and you must use the g-inverse of $(X'X)$.

(I would have put this in a comment instead of an answer, but I apparently do not yet have enough reputation to comment.)

Comment: It's given that $X$ is not necessarily of full rank, but I'm starting to get a couple ideas... I'll update as I go along

Comment: I'll edit my answer to update this, but X is necessarily not full rank.  For a matrix to be of full rank, it must be invertible.  For it to be invertible, it must be a square matrix.  Since $X$ is $m\times n$ and $m<n$, $X$ cannot be full rank.  Thus $(X'X)$ has infinite g-inverses but no unique inverse.